# define multiple Global scope for a model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Post Model with **SoftDelete** capability and an **active** boolean field to determine Post active status.

```
class Post extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

In addition to, Post Model has a `start_date` field that hold start date of publish post.

And now , I want to use [Anonymous GlobalScope Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes) to filter and fetch only active posts and those theirs `start_dat`e is NULL or less than Now() In addition to the non Soft Deleted models.

For that I added this to `Post` Model :

```
protected static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            static::addGlobalScope('active', function(Builder $builder){
                $builder->where('active',1);
            });

            static::addGlobalScope('scheduled', function(Builder $builder){
                $builder
                    ->whereNull('start_date')->orWhere(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now());
                    });
            });
        }
```

`active` global scope alone, works fine but when I add second scope named `scheduled`, returns all records include soft Deleted and inActive models.

what is Problem? I can not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `orWhere`. In these instances, using the Laravel Debug Bar to see the Raw SQL is very helpful, because I'd bet money your select statement looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND active=1 AND state_date IS NULL OR (start_Date <= now())`

That would select anything that meets the one OR criterion.

To fix that, you should make `scheduled` look like this.

```
static::addGlobalScope('scheduled', function(Builder $builder) {
    $builder->where(function($query)) {
        $query->whereNull('start_date');
        $query->orWhere('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now());
    });
});
```

Which would (hopefully) make your query look like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND active=1 AND (state_date IS NULL OR start_Date <= now())`

Which is what I think you want.